# Script to check TLS/SSL certificate expiration date works with google.com but not https://google.com

Tags: linux, bash

I've wrote the following code and the output should be:

- When the SSL certificate will expire
- The status code of a browser

The problem is that if I insert https://www.google.com or http://www.google.com I get an error. If I try with google.com it's working correctly.

Any idea?

```
read -p "Please insert the url: " url

certificate_file=$(mktemp)
echo -n | openssl s_client -servername "$url" -connect "$url":443 2>/dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > $certificate_file
date=$(openssl x509 -in $certificate_file -enddate -noout | sed "s/.*=\(.*\)/\1/")
date_s=$(date -d "${date}" +%s)
now_s=$(date -d now +%s)
date_diff=$(( (date_s - now_s) / 86400 ))

if [[ "$date_diff" -gt "1" ]]; then

echo "Certificate expires in: $date_diff days"

else
    echo "$url does not use SSL Certificates"

fi

response=$(curl -s -w "%{http_code}" $url)

http_code=$(tail -n1 <<< "$response") 

if [[ "$http_code" == "200" ]]; then

    echo "OK for: $http_code"

elif [[ "http_code" != "200" ]]; then
    echo "HTTP code: $http_code"

elif [[ "http_code" == "408" ]]; then
    echo "Request Timeout"

fi
```

The error code is the following:

```
Please insert the url: https:/www.yahoo.com   
unable to load certificate
140381863350720:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
https:/www.yahoo.com does not use SSL Certificates
HTTP code: Regional Redirect302
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `-connect` flag for `openssl s_client` takes a `host:port`, but you're providing a URL.  So your `openssl s_client` command is failing with an error like this:

```
s_client: -connect argument or target parameter malformed or ambiguous
```

But you discard this error message with `2>/dev/null`, so it doesn't show up in your output.  When the `openssl s_client` command fails, you won't have any data in `$certificate_file`.  This results in the `Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE` error you see in your output.

To fix, you'll need to convert `$url` to a hostname before using it as the argument to `-connect`.